# spring batch insert into oracle database issue

Tags: oracle, spring-batch

I have a spring batch example where I read from a Flat file and write into Oracle  database. when I create the oracle table the first time using Oracle developer , the example work perfect , but when I delete all the records and run the spring batch example the application stay in running mode (stop at the point wher insert in table) and not finish until I manually (using oracle SQL Developer ) add a record in the table , so it s continue running and complete perfectly . Is that have a problem with the table that I'm using in oracle (I m not an expert in oracle database).
any help or suggestion please?

Comment: if you have    a question . I can answer or if you need more details .

Comment: yes please, what do you mean by "until I manually add a record in the table"? Are you sure the previous run has finished? Probably there is a lock on the table preventing the second run to insert records? I can't see what could go wrong with the description you gave.

Comment: sorry to be unclear , I used  Oracle Sql Developer to add a record . yes I m sure that the first run finished .  and more if I add manually using Oracl Sql  developer a record in the table and after that run the spring batch example it s works fine.

Comment: When you run the spring batch from the application, are you committing your changes? When you are doing large batch operations in Oracle, the database will place a lock on the table until the transaction is either committed or rolled back. If you are not doing that when you run your batch from within the application, my guess is that whatever you're doing from the application side is placing a lock on the table, and said lock is not removed until you manually commit your changes by adding a record to the table. 

Try adding a commit point at the end of your application process to test.

Comment: @cdb_dba :thank you for your reply , I  think (correct me please if I m wrong) spring batch commit changes because I have the commit-interval=20  in the job definition .  In a n other scenario if I run the spring batch application after I added a record in the table , so it run correctly , and I DELETE all the records but LEAVE  only the field that I added and run spring batch application again it will work fine .

Comment: @cdb_dba : you are right : the problem was because when I DELETE from the table manually , I just run delete from  request , but I should run commit after that because I don t have experience with Oracle Database . can you just put your comment to accept it as a question .

Comment: Glad to help! Sorry for the lack of response, things have been busy on my side due to the upcoming holidays. Will do shortly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the spring batch from the application, are you committing your changes? When you are doing large batch operations in Oracle, the database will place a lock on the table until the transaction is either `committed` or `rolled back`. If you are not doing that when you run your batch from within the application, my guess is that whatever you're doing from the application side is placing a lock on the table, and said lock is not removed until you manually `commit` your changes by adding a record to the table. Try adding a `commit` point at the end of your application process to test.